# List of parameter options in Animation Nodes

Tags: interface, animation-nodes

I see there are boolean nodes, but is there any way to create list of named options  so that the a user can pick one and specific part of tree will be executed?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to create an enum?

Comment: Make Group Nodes for the specific parts of your node-tree then with the help of named list and boolean node, you can select specific group node based on the name.

Comment: Yes I want to create an enum that ideally user could choose single option from drop-down list.

Comment: This is currently not possible as far as I know.